# taxonomy_template filter do not loads custom taxonomy template properly

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, templates

I'm using [taxonomy_template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomy_template) filter in my **plugin** to load a template file for **custom user taxonomies**. This is the code I'm using

```
 add_filter( 'taxonomy_template', 'get_custom_taxonomy_template' );
 function get_custom_taxonomy_template($template) {

   $taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');

   if (strpos($taxonomy,'rcm_user_') !== false) {
      $taxonomy_template = UT_TEMPLATES_URL ."user-taxonomy-template.php";
      $file_headers = @get_headers($taxonomy_template);
      if( $file_headers[0] != 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'){
         return $taxonomy_template;
      }
   }
   return $template; 
}
```

It loads the file but I get fatal error for wordpress functions like

```
get_header(), _e()
```

I've tried using default theme, saving permalink structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with `UT_TEMPLATES_URL`used for including the template.

I was using `file URL` and not `file PATH` which was creating the issue.

Modifying the `UT_TEMPLATES_URL`, to `FILE PATH` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The get_query_var function requires the wp_query object, and it is not within your functions scope - so you need to include it:

```
global $wp_query;
```

This should work.

--

Jørgen Juel

Comment: That function is working quiet ok, problem is with template inclusion.

I'm getting proper values for get_query_var('taxonomy')

Comment: get_query_var() itslef uses $wp_query, I need not use $wp_query in my function.